# Were there any external markings or features that allow the Gemini VI and VII capsules to be identified in photographs taken on-orbit?

Tags: history, identify-this-object, project-gemini

(Inspired by [What are these on the Gemini Spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/61892/6944))

Gemini VI-A and VII rendezvoused and pictures of the spacecraft were taken.

[image]

Given only the pictures and no other information, are there markings or external features that allow one spacecraft to be distinguished from the other?

NASA Images site search link https://images.nasa.gov/search?q=gemini%20rendezvous&page=1&media=image&yearStart=1920&yearEnd=2023

Comment: If there's a "Beat Army" sign in the window, it's Gemini VI-A.